# SignalR Connection Limit reached in Windows 7 IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know if we deploy SignalR app in default IIS which comes with windows 7 then we we can have only 10 active connection to SignalR app after that it rejects any incoming request.

**but i want to know what are the different methods available to overcome with this issue please guide me.**

Answer (score 0):

Your limitation comes from the desktop version of Windows. If you install the app on a Windows Server, you will have much higher limit. The default limit of concurrent requests per application in SignalR is 5000, which you can change.

Check **IIS configurations settings** and **ASP.NET configuration settings** in the [Performance section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance#design-considerations) of the official documentation for ideas.

Obviously, there is always a limit. There are people who report 20,000-30,000 connections but that is very subjective, dependant on the code, threading decisions, and server capacity.